# how can i use variables correctly in classes?

Tags: python, class

i made three classes, one to decide the position of a point on a 2d space.
and second, a function, to calcule the distance between two points.
and a third to calculate wether a point is in a circle close to a point, but this third one just doesnt work and i cant figure out why

```
class Point():
    """ Represents a point in 2D coordinates. 
    """
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

```
def distance(point_1, point_2)-> float:         #moet nog typehints toevoegen maar weet niet welke hints ik moet gebruiken
    """ 
    This function calculates the eaclidean distance between two points and returns the result.
    :param: point_1 - is a point on a 2D space
    :param: point_2 - is a point on a 2D space
    """
    distance_x: int = point_1.x - point_2.x
    distance_y: int = point_1.y - point_2.y
    euclidean_distance: int = sqrt((distance_x ** 2) + (distance_y ** 2))
    return euclidean_distance
```

```
class Circle:
    
    def __init__(self, center, radius) -> None:
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius

    

    def inside_circle(input_circle)-> bool:
        if distance(center, input_circle) > radius:
            return False
        else:
            return True
        

center = Point(2,3)
circle = Circle(center, 2)

point = Point(1,5)

circle.inside_circle(point)
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not specific enough to be answerable.  Read [ask].

Comment: In the `inside_circle` function you don't use `self` which you should since it is a member function.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of class instance functions, by convention, should be `self`. It's implicitly added, so you're probably seeing some error like "2 arguments provided, expected 1"

```
def inside_circle(self, input_circle)-> bool:
    return distance(self.center, input_circle) <= radius
```

Also, I assume you meant to define that function inside the Point class, not test if a circle is inside another circle (that's how the function reads)? Because you're passing just a point instance as `inner_circle`. In other words, `point.inside_circle(circle)`

Or you can rename the function `encompasses_point`, or `contains_point`. But then you still should rename the parameter.